# Ubuntu 17.10 lid close: different behaviors on AC or battery?

Tags: 17.10, power-management, laptop, lid

I would like different behaviors on lid closing depending on AC is plugged (do nothing) or not (suspend). My laptop is a DELL Latitude under 64-bit Ubuntu 17.10. What I already tried:

- Using GNOME Tweaks. It works well to define the overall lid behavior, but it does not change with AC/battery status.
- Using dconf shows some interesting settings (`lid-close-ac-action` and `lid-close-battery-action`), but they are always overriden by the above discussed GNOME Tweaks settings.
- Manually editing (as root) `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` and commenting/uncommenting/changing the values of `HandleLidSwitch`, `HandleLidSwitchDocked` and `LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited` seem to have no effect whatsoever.
- Choosing X or (default) Wayland does not seem to change anything either.

So what can I do? These settings used to work on previous Ubuntu versions, and forgetting to suspend while on battery leads to a fast drain of the battery within 24-48 hours...

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! I found the solution following the links on this other page, thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this is a known issue apparently, and a working patch (at least for me) can be found [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1722286):